# reformat section headings to include text

Tags: sectioning, environments

I'm sure that there's a easy answer, but I've reached the point of frustration trying different things with the \renew command.

I want to reformat all section headings to include the text "Question" with automatic numbering. Now, I have:

```
\section{Question 1}
\section{Question 2}
\section{Question 3}
```

with the expected results. I would like my section headings all to appear as follows by simply using

```
\section{}
\section{}
\section{}
```

so that the text appears like this

```
Question 1
Question 2
Question 3
```

Is this possible, as if so, does anyone have a hint? Thanks much, CC.

Comment: Why don't you use an enumerate environment? It would be easy to do with `enumitem`.

Answer (score 4):

Would you be happy with something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{qnumber}
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}

\newcommand{\newquestion}{\addtocounter{qnumber}{1}\section*{Question \theqnumber}}

\begin{document}

\newquestion

abc

\newquestion

cdf

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks. I suppose I was looking for the answer to the wrong question. Now that I know the right question it's as easy as I thought it would be ... but I did spend some effort attempting to answer the wrong question.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to samcarter's solution, but uses `\section` (no argument needed):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldsection\section% Store \section in \oldsection
\renewcommand{\section}{% Update \section
  \refstepcounter{section}% Step section counter
  \oldsection*{Question~\thesection}}% Write a \section* with a specific header

\begin{document}

\section

Some content.

\section

Some more content.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I may have been on the right track, but I tried to manipulate \section{} directly. I don't know if that would have worked, but it didn't work as I attempted it.